# How to document the argument of BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(Object)?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a `DoWorkEventHandler` that requires an argument on the `RunWorkerAsync` call to work.

```
public static void ProcessData(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Argument == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        MyType argument;
        try
        {
            argument = (MyType)e.Argument;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Argument passed is not from type MyType");
        }
    /* ... */
}
```

It will throw if the user executes `RunWorkerAsync` without argument, passing a `null`, or passing and argument that can't be cast into `MyType`.

I can do something like this to document this need

```
/// <summary>...</summary>
/// <param name="e">e.Argument must be of type MyType</param>
public static void ProcessData(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) { /*...*/ }
```

But still, after the user writes this

```
var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += ProcessData;
```

When s/he writes this line

```
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

The IDE will not show the need of the argument.

There is any way to make the IDE show the user that info?

If not, how should I document this?

**Edit:** <strike>I can't use a wrapper arount RunWorkerAsync() like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27203624/2215451).</strike> The DoWork is implemented on the model, and the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted are implemented on the viewmodel, because each viewmodel implements a different handler.

**Edit2:** Actually @usr answer will do the trick. If I declare the background worker in the model, and expose simply the 2 delegates it will do the trick, allowing me to separate completely business from design, allowing the view/viewmodel to implement ProcessChanged and RunWorkerCompleted, without worrying about other details, and being able to effectively use a wrapper.

Comment: Just leave it up to the client programmer to decide if he wants to use a BackgroundWorker.  Or a Task or a Thread or QUWI or async/await.  So do *not* declare the argument DoWorkEventArgs, that forces him into making the wrong decisions.  Declare it as MyType instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Document this simply by saying:

```
var myArg = (MyType)e.Argument;
```

That's 100% clear about nullness and the correct type.

A usage error results in a crash like it should be. This is a crash that only devs see. The root cause will be obvious. If you want to make it even more obvious:

```
Debug.Assert(e.Argument is MyType);
var myArg = (MyType)e.Argument;
```

If you want the documentation to appear at the call site of `RunWorkerAsync` wrap it:

```
void StartMyWorker(MyType arg) { ... }
```

Now the IDE shows you the right type.

Comment: Yes, wrap it. A little curious why the typecast or `Debug.Assert` rather than a null check and an `ArgumentNullException`.

Comment: @JimMischel this is not an expected case. I wouldn't invest more time in it. If this was a library you would have to implement a better response than simply crashing the process.

Comment: Nice the `Debug.Assert`

Comment: In the end, this was truly the way to go ^_^